# Disabling the "no paper" beep on an XPrinter XP-80C

Tags: printing, xprinter

I have an XPrinter XP-80C with a modified form factor that fits into a certain model of kiosk. I'm controling it from a .NET application via the ESCPOS_NET Nuget package. When the printer is on and there is no paper detected in the feeder, (whether it's because the paper has run out or the cover is open), the printer keeps beeping incessantly. This is a problem, as we'll be putting these kiosks into waiting rooms at doctors' offices. There are plenty of scenarios I can think of off the top of my head where the paper won't be replaced immediately: the nurse is busy drawing blood, the office ran out of printer paper, etc.

You could turn off the printer to get rid of the beeping, but it's built into the kiosk frame and you need a special key to open the printer panel. Suppose the custodian has the key and he's off at the other end of the hospital changing a light bulb.

I've been looking for a way to disable the beeping. I've tried a test tool I downloaded from the XPrinter website. This allowed me to get rid of the "Cut With Beep" sound, but there doesn't seem to be a setting for beeping when there is no paper. I've also tried to find a command I could send to the printer from the application. So far I've been unsuccessful.

I should note that all I want to disable is the beep - not the whole paper detection. Our application is listening for events from the printer, and when a "low paper" or "no paper" event is raised we send notifications to designated people (making the beeps redundant in addition to being obnoxious). Therefore I need paper detection to work. Just without the beep.